# Border Not Viewed at 100% (LaTeX and PDF)

Tags: pdf

I am incorporating .pdf image in LaTeX. The .pdf files work perfectly on all resolutions, however, once i insert them in LaTeX and subsequently generate the complete .pdf document, one of the borders of the images disappears when viewing it at 100% resolution. It, nevertheless, works fine for the other resolutions.

Any clues?

Comment: You mean that the border is not visible when you inspect the PDF in your viewer? That is a common problem of the rasterisation done by PDF viewers to display the PDF on screen and nothing you need to worry about.

Comment: True, the border doesn't appear for some images while it would appear for others. Is there a way around this 'rasterisation'? I am actually working on an important document and it seems too awkward to present it like this.

Comment: I repeat my question (hopefully a bit clearer): Is this only for certain magnifications of your PDF viewer (without changes to the PDF)? If so, try the settings of your viewer, or changing the viewer.

Comment: Yes, it's for certain magnifications of PDF viewer. I am with Adobe but it seems that it's useless in this particular case.

Comment: @Qureshi: I have tried to solve the problem of vanishing rules in tabulars (in some PDF viewers at some levels of zoom) with my extension `nicematrix`. Maybe I will be able to analyze your problem but it's not possible without the exact files. If you want, you can send me a mail (fpantigny arobase wanadoo.fr)